# CSS Stylesheet tools

Tags: javascript, css

What are some known tools for the development of css stylesheets that will produce cross browser css's ?

Is there something that I can run my css though to product cross browser css's or maybe another 'language' I could pickup that will output cross browser css ?

Comment: IMHO - Mastering `CSS` and browser incompatibilities/corner cases is your best option. I still haven't warmed to any of the `CSS` frameworks. `Raw CSS` works for me...

Comment: Doesn't exist.  You have to understand css and code to the known browser variances.  Besides, how far do you want to go: support IE7 (takes some work)? Support IE6 (takes a lot MORE work, and sometimes cannot get a 100% result on how you want it to render)? Support IE5 or earlier?  Write clean, compliant code and you'll be in a much stronger position to render properly cross-browser.

Comment: There is a bit of a gap there — we could do with a CSS tool that flags detectable issues (which would mostly be IE issues). I’m not sure that all cross-browser bugs would be detectable just from parsing the code, but such a tool could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) meets what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

While @Xander and @cale_b are perfectly correct, there are some steps you can take to make life slightly easier.

Firstly, most of the time, most browsers these days are fairly consistent, and the differences they do have are fairly minor. There are two exceptions to this, (which is possibly where your question is coming from:

1. Older versions of Internet Explorer, particularly IE6 and IE7.
2. Things labelled "CSS3" that are often only implemented with vendor prefixes.

So, the way I work around these issues is in a three step process:

1. Create vanilla CSS code that works well in modern browsers. That is, just write standard CSS and test it in one or two up-to-date browsers.
2. If I need advanced "CSS3" features, I use a generator like [CSS3 please"](http://css3please.com/) (you can find more on [this SitePoint post](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-best-css3-code-generators/))
3. Once everything is working to my satisfaction in modern browsers, I then assess the situation in IE6 and IE7. If everything is a mess, I start out by using the wonderful [IE6 fixer](http://www.onderhond.com/tools/ie6fixer/). Once the layout is vaguely OK in these browsers, I will then assess how much "CSS3" support is needed and look for polyfills. Generally the [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) tool covers most of what I need for this. Then I tackle the tricky task of debugging any remaining idiosyncrasies for these browsers, and I'm done.

I hope that helps.